# regex extract exact one string

Tags: regex

I have two strings:

1. "John Johnson Phone Number"
2. "John Johnson Alternate Phone Number"

Need to extract first one, name and last name might change

I was matching first string with this regex as Name and Last name might change.

```
^\w+ \w+( \w+)? Phone Number$
```

Seems pretty easy but I've brain freeze cannot solve it for few hours.
Issue now that same regex picks up 2nd string which I do not want to be picked up.

Maybe someone could give me a hint how to match only first string and do not take strings which contains Alternate word? Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question? What does the surrounding Go code look like and how are the strings represented?

Comment: sorry, i do not need a code, i just need a regex

Comment: But which regex will work depends on what the data and ultimately the code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to capture the whole string, and extract the words before "Phone number". You can do this with capture groups. You can name your capture groups to such that you do not have to worry about which index number the group is at (if you add/remove groups later).

The syntax is `(?P<name>...)`.

So for your situation I put the first two `\w+` into the capture group `name`. The returned `matches` is the full string matched in index 0. Indices after are the subgroups. You can use `re.SubexpIndex("name")` to find the correct subgroup index for the named subgroup `name`.

https://goplay.tools/snippet/dcwWg3FBWUd

```golang
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^(?P<name>\w+ \w+)( \w+)? Phone Number$`)
    str := "John Johnson Alternate Phone Number"
    index := re.SubexpIndex("name")
    matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(str)
    if len(matches) > 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s\n", matches[index])
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No Match")
    }
```

**EDIT**: I thought this was a golang question :facepalm:

This still works using capture groups to extract the relevant sub matches out.

Comment: thanks for the code. I made a mistake not to describe that I do not need a code, sorry for that. I want to extract/match everything except Alternate and string which contains alternate just by using regex (without any code) Sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: I have no idea why, but this question came up under the `[go]` tag for me at first. Really sorry, didn't realize you want pure regex. Does capture groups do what you want? Or do you really need to skip certain words in the match? Because that gets very complicated.